# Is volatile needed, in case of only synchronized access

Tags: java, concurrency

Shall the `emitting` variable be volatile? the `emit()` method is called from different threads, and emit must be visible.
But it is accessed in `synchronized` blocks only. The `// ...` are places where the work is done, but `emitting` is not referenced here.

So, if the structure of `synchronized` is fix, do I still need a `volatile` for `emitting` or not? (and why?)

```
static final class C {
    boolean emitting = false; // shall be volatile ?

    public void emit() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (emitting) {
                return;
            }
            // ...
            emitting = true;
        }

        // ...

        synchronized (this) {
            if (!condition()) {
                emitting = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
```

Frank

Answer (score 14):

If it is accessed only from `synchronized` blocks is not needed the `volatile` keyword.

Synchronized guarantees that changes to variables accessed inside the synchronized block are visible to all threads entering a synchronized block.

From the book *Java concurrency in practice*:

> To publish an object **safely**, both the reference to the
>   object and the object's state must be made visible to other
>   threads at the same time. A properly constructed object can be safely published by:
>
> - Initializing an object reference from a static initializer;
> - Storing a reference to it into a volatile field or Atomic Reference
>     ;
> - Storing a reference to it into a final field of a properly constructed object;
> - **Storing  a reference to it into  a field that is properly *guarded by a lock*.**

**Note:** *guarded by a lock* means entered in a synchronized block

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a query if you could please answer. If synchronized block is made on Object1 and another Object2's state is being accessed within that synchronized block on Object1, is it still safe ?

Comment: @nits.kk it is safe until Object2 state is not modified from outside the synchronized block. Or it is modified from a synchronized block on a variable different from Object1

Comment: thanks @Davide Lorenzo for the clarification...