# Is it mandatory to declare a variable volatile when I have a synchronized block to increment an int in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, synchronized

I'm learning about concurrency in Java and I'm watching a YouTube video. It is an explanation about increment operation in a multi-threading environment. The solution for that could be a volatile variable or a synchronized block. But my question is, if I use a synchronized block do I need to use also volatile variable. Is not enough if I have a synchronized block? I see that the instructor makes the method synchronized and also makes the variable volatile. In my opinion is enough to make the method synchronized because when a thread enters the synchronized method it gets the value of the variable from main memory and when the thread exits the synchronized method it sends the value directly to main memory and it will be available for other threads. So I don't think it is mandatory to make the variable volatile.

This is the code:

```
public class ClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = null;
        Counter counter = new Counter();

        try {
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

            Runnable task1 = () -> {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 20000; i++) {
                    counter.increment();
                }
            };

            Runnable task2 = () -> {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 80000; i++) {
                    counter.increment();
                }
            };

            executorService.submit(task1);
            executorService.submit(task2);
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            System.out.println("Final counter value: " + counter.getCounter());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

… and:

```
public class Counter {
    private int counter;
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
    public synchronized void increment() {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Is it mandatory to declare the counter variable volatile?

Comment: @SolomonSlow That is not correct, given `getCounter()` is not synchronized, the `counter` field must be marked `volatile` to see its latest state.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, D'Oh! I didn't read carefully enough. But I disagree that `counter` _must_ be declared `volatile`. As you point out, you could also fix the problem by declaring `getCounter` to be `synchronized`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Though in this specific case it will work, because `getCounter()` is only called after `awaitTermination` on the executor service, which also establish a happens-before with all writes done by the threads from the executor service.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You're right, it can also be solved by marking the method `synchronized`, though I'd prefer marking it `volatile` over using `synchronized` for the get.

Comment: Related: [*Is volatile needed, in case of only synchronized access*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32974336/642706) and [*Java - is volatile required with synchronized?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22862226/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For correct behaviour of the `Counter` class, you will either need to mark the `counter` field `volatile`, or you need to make the `getCounter()` method `synchronized` as well, or alternatively, get rid of the `Counter` class and use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

In the specific example of your code, it will probably work correctly, but that is - again probably - because you call `awaitTermination` on the executor service, and the submitted tasks will likely finish before the timeout expires. I think, but do not know for sure, this will establish a happens-before relationship between the tasks executed on the executor threads, and thus your main thread will be guaranteed to see the latest value of `counter`.

However, absent such a happens-before relationship, the main thread (or any other thread) is not guaranteed to see the latest value of `counter`, it could see any intermediate state, including the initial value of `0`. To establish such a happens-before, you will need to mark the field `volatile`, or use `synchronized` on the method, as this will guarantee that the latest written value is read.

As an aside, calling `awaitTermination` without calling `shutdown()` on the executor service is not correct.

Comment: Note to the reader: Regarding proper shutdown of an executor service, see the boilerplate code given in the `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` method in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Similar code is used as the default implementation of [`ExecutorService#close`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#close()).

Answer (score 1):

### `Atomic…`

As mentioned in the correct [Answer by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506903/642706), an alternative to using `synchronized`/`volatile` is the use of the `Atomic…` classes.

I prefer the `Atomic…` approach because it makes very clear to the reader *what* resources you are concerned about protecting from multi-threaded access/manipulation. And using `Atomic…` makes quite clear *how* you intend to protect those resources.

Furthermore, using `Atomic…` often simplifies the code and the reader’s comprehension.

### Properly shutting down executor service

That same Answer by Mark Rotteveel is also correct in pointing out that your code does not properly shut down the executor service. To do so properly, either:

- Use the boilerplate code in `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` method given on the Javadoc of `ExecutorService`, or…
- Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close the executor service after it completes its tasks (within a day).

I prefer the second approach, try-with-resources.

### Example code

Let's use both these concepts (`Atomic…` & auto-closing of executor service) in this revised code.

```java
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ClientTest
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger ( );

        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 2 ) ;
        )
        {
            Runnable task1 = ( ) -> {
                for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 20_000 ; i++ )
                {
                    counter.incrementAndGet ( );
                }
            };

            Runnable task2 = ( ) -> {
                for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 80_000 ; i++ )
                {
                    counter.incrementAndGet ( );
                }
            };

            executorService.submit ( task1 );
            executorService.submit ( task2 );
        }
        System.out.println ( "Final counter value: %,d".formatted ( counter.get ( ) ) );
    }
}
```

> Final counter value: 100,000

I am concerned about our `AtomicInteger` named `counter` here being a local variable. I am not sure if being a local variable presents a visibility problem. I always use the `Atomic…` variables as a `final` instance member (or `static`) variable that is populated on its declaration line as a simple way to ensure thread-safety.

Comment: Using an `AtomicInteger` in a local variable like this does not have any visibility concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the AtomicInteger approach! I want to ask you if the `compareAndGet()` is an implementation of the `compareAndSwap(expected value, new value)` functionality.  And if yes then who is the expected value in this example? I know that compare and swap will compare the value of the `AtomicInteger counter` with the value of the expected value, and if has the expected value, it swaps the value with a new value. The new value probably is the value of the `counter` incremented with 1, but who is the expected value?

Comment: @elvis That should be posted as a new Question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println ( "Final counter value: %,d".formatted ( counter.get ( ) ) );` you can simply write `System.out.printf("Final counter value: %,d%n", counter.get());` or, if you prefer methods with “format” in their names, `System.out.format("Final counter value: %,d%n", counter.get());`